# Disable access to "Delete", "Edit", "Upload New Version" on the file previewer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files

I use [lightning:fileCard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/documentation) and [e.lightning:openFiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:openFiles/example) components in my lightning component (that I use inside a community)

In 1 stage on my component, I wish to display a file preview, and to not give the user any option to change the file.

**MARKUP**

```
<tr onclick="{!c.filePreview}" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Click to preview file" id="{!v.ContentDocumentId}">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
filePreview: function(component, event, helper) {
    var contentId = event.currentTarget.id;
    $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({
        recordIds: [contentId]
    });
},
```

**QUESTION**
Is it possible to block access to update the file inside the file previewer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did some analysis and found these `Delete`, `Edit`, `Upload New Version` option came because user has these permissions on that record. If in sharing setting for that record is set with `private` and user has only `viewers` permission like :
[image]

he would not be able to see these buttons :
[image]

We can't hide them, these are controlled by permissions.

Comment: I do not understand what do you suggest to do - how do I `remove file actions slds-file__actions-menu` ?

Comment: Use `slds-file slds-file_card` and as a part part of customization don't add `slds-file__actions-menu`

Comment: I do not use any css - I use only the `$A.get('e.lightning:openFiles')` event which opens a standard component

Comment: @ItaiShmida please check my updated answer.